# How to read 2 columns of .txt file & store it in x & y variables in python

Tags: python, file, file-read, txt

**This is the data of .txt file.(2 columns)**

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
7.0032,11.854
5.8598,6.8233
8.3829,11.886
7.4764,4.3483
8.5781,12.0
6.4862,6.5987
5.0546,3.8166
5.7107,3.2522
```

Comment: You can use pandas to read the file into a df and play around with it.

Comment: @ShivangiSingh Can u please share the code of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `csv reader`

```py
import csv
x = []
y = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
```

**Output**:

```py
>>x
[6.1101, 5.5277, 8.5186, 7.0032, 5.8598, 8.3829, 7.4764, 8.5781, 6.4862, 5.0546, 5.7107]
>>y
[17.592, 9.1302, 13.662, 11.854, 6.8233, 11.886, 4.3483, 12.0, 6.5987, 3.8166, 3.2522]
```

Comment: I got this error    left,right =  row.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: That was old solution,  check with the updated one